# Batch file doesn't pause after loop

Tags: batch-file

Here's my batch file:

```
@echo off
set rdslist=rds-instance-1 rds-instance-2

:retryaction
set /P action=Would you like to (1)start or (2)stop these instances %rdslist%:

IF %action%==1 (
    set command=start
    goto :start
)
IF %action%==2 (
    set command=stop
    goto :start
)

goto :retryaction

:start
(for %%a in (%rdslist%) do (
    aws rds %command%-db-instance --db-instance-identifier %%a
))
pause
```

It doesn't pause after I run it, but if I place the `pause` before or inside the for loop it pauses.

Comment: Try changing `aws` to `call aws`.

Comment: GOTO does not require a colon for the label. Only need it for CALL.

Comment: @Squashman the colon after `goto` should only affect script execution when the label is `eof`...

Comment: @SomethingDark that worked, thanks. Add it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws` is another script, not a program. When a batch script executes another batch script without using the `call` command, program flow is permanently transferred to that second script and does not return to the first script upon completion. When `call` is used, the second script is run and then flow is returned to the parent script.

Change your `for` loop to

```
for %%a in (%rdslist%) do (
    call aws rds %command%-db-instance --db-instance-identifier %%a
)
```

so that your initial script will keep running; otherwise, the script stops after  the first instance is completed.